# Iterate on a golang array/slice without using for statement

Tags: arrays, go

Is it possible to iterate on a golang array/slice without using 'for' statement?

Comment: I don't think asking "for doing what" is appropriate to this question since the question is so clear that he asked about existence of an alternative way to iterate. He has his purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276054/12817546.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `goto` statement (not recommended).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    my_slice := []string {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

    index := 0

back:
    if index < len(my_slice) {
        fmt.Println(my_slice[index])
        index += 1
        goto back
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @LeoCorrea you could use a recursive function to iterate over a slice. A tail recursion could prevent the stack overflow mentioned by @vutran.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func num(a []string, i int) {
    if i >= len(a) {
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println(i, a[i]) //0 a 1 b 2 c
        i += 1
        num(a, i) //tail recursion
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    i := 0
    num(a, i)
}
```

A possibly more readable but less pure example could use an anonymous function. See https://play.golang.org/p/Qen6BKviWuE.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a recursive function to iterate over the slice but why would you want to not use a `for` loop?

Comment: Warning for anyone who tries to use recursive rather than a `for`, don't use recursive for too many loops, it will flood the stack memory causing `stack overflow` error and `stackoverflow.com` look up.

Comment: Right, this is a good explanation http://www.goinggo.net/2013/09/recursion-and-tail-calls-in-go_26.html

Comment: Good answer +1. I might want to use a recursive if I wanted to use pure functions with minimal side-effects i.e. functional programming. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276054/12817546.

Answer (score 0):

Go doesn't have different loop keywords like `for` or `while`, it just has `for` which has a few different forms